# How to lock the Screen customly? Just like WaveSecure in Android

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to do a demo just like WaveSecure, which win Android Develop Challenge 2 with a third place. Now I have a problem in locking the screen customly, so I want to know how WaveSecure achieve its locking function, as the following picture show:

[image]

When the mobile is locked, WaveSecure can require customer to input their own password. So I think WaveSecure must replace Android's original locking function.

And I also google it, but I didn't find anything helpful. I only find two packages may be helpful. They are:

- android.app.KeyguardManager
- android.os.PowerManager

But after I reading the Android Docs, I still can't have an idea on it.

Can you help me? Thx:)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to the exact same question for a while. Apparently, after 2.0 onwards the device manager privileges for the app level were removed. But with Froyo - 2.2  the device policy manager is revealed granting us developers a multitude of administrative level controls.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html